# How to do a simple operation that normally requires double for loops in [R]?

Tags: r

I´m quite new to R and I´m coming from a c++ background. I have a data frame with multiple rows and columns. My question is how can I do this in a different manner because it takes for ever to run. I have over 60 thousand rows and around 15 columns. Is there a better way to do this? Help is greatly appreciated!

```
counter <-0

 for(j in 7:length(SeaStateData[3,]))
 {
  for( i in 1:length(SeaStateData[,3]))
      {


        if(!is.na(SeaStateData[i,j]) & !is.na(SeaStateData[i+1,j]))
        if(SeaStateData[i,j] == SeaStateData[i+1,j])
         {
          counter <- counter + 1
         }

       }
 }
```

Comment: Your code should cause an error, as you access row `i+1` but include the case where `i` equals the number of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
nr <- nrow(SeaStateData)
nc <- ncol(SeaStateData)
counter <- sum(SeaStateData[1:(nr - 1), 7:nc] ==
               SeaStateData[2:nr, 7:nc],
               na.rm = TRUE)
```

The subsets represent two submatrices, with a relative offset of one row. The `==` operator will yield a logical vector (in this case a matrix, which is just a vector with added dimension information) containing `TRUE` if two items match, `FALSE` if they differ, and `NA` if one of them is `NA`. The `sum` over a logical vector counts all `TRUE` values. The `na.rm` attribute tells it to drop `NA` values; otherwise the `sum` would be `NA` as well. `sum(…, na.rm = TRUE)` is roughly the same as `sum(na.omit(…))`.